# how to handle my skills as aclass model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating my portfolio which I handled its template from bootstrap templates into a django project, I need to make skills section in template comes from a model called "skills" to be able to add more skills later.but they mentioned as list items and fontawesome icons in the template so which model field could handle that? note that not all of them are fontawsome icons . here is code in template:

Skills

```
    <div class="subheading mb-3">Programming Languages &amp; Tools</div>
    <ul class="list-inline dev-icons">

      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <i class="fab fa-js-square"></i>
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <i class="fab fa-sass"></i>
      </li>

      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <i class="fab fa-python"></i>
      </li>

      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <img class="img-fluid img-profile  mx-auto mb-2" src="{% static 'img/sql.png' %}">
      </li>
      <li class="list-inline-item">
        <img id="logo" src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}">
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="subheading mb-3">Duties & Responsibilities</div>
    <ul class="fa-ul mb-0">
      <li>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>
        Write reusable, testable, and efficient code.</li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>
        Design and implement of low-latency, high-availability, and performant applications.</li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>
        Integration of user-facing elements developed by front-end developers with server side logic.</li>
      <li>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>
        Implementation of security and data protection</li>
        <li>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>
        Integration of data storage solutions</li>
        <li>
        <i class="fa-li fa fa-check"></i>
        Work collaboratively with design team to understand end user requirements to provide technical solutions and for the implementation of new software features</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i would suggest to simply create a model with a field Charfield:

models.py:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    # name will make your skill easier to find in your admin
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

in your view you'll be able to collect all the skills:

```
def skills_view(request):
    skills = Skills.objects.all()
    return render(request, "template.html", {
        'skills'=skills,
    }
```

in the template display the skills:

```
{% for skill in skills %}
    <li class="list-inline-item">
            <i class="{{skill.skill}}"></i>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

I would do something like this if i understood well
Register the model in admin to add your skills

Comment: so fontawsome CDN will work from model? and how about static img ?

Comment: if i remember well, you just have to load fontawsome in your html and you can stock all your fontawsome pictos in your db through the model.